# DAX PowerBI - DIVIDE

Tags: powerbi, dax

Am trying to use DIVIDE in DAX - Power BI

```
Test = divide(-165679.88*100,1741653.04)
```

But am getting result as `-9.51` (-ve) instead `9.51`  ... why?

Comment: Can it be that you have a typo? You seem to have a minut sign before 165679.88*100

Comment: oops, my fault... yes that works fine. :)